# PHP 5.2.x: $_POST is empty when any field has value of "drop anywords from anywords"?

Tags: php, form-submit, php-5.2

Very weird bug!

When at least 1 form field has value of "zeroOrMoreWords drop oneOrMoreWords from oneOrMoreWords", the $_POST comes empty! Just to confirm to myself I'm not crazy, I tried the same thing on another website that uses PHP 5.2.11 and happens the same thing!

I tried:

- PHP 5.2.8 = $_POST comes empty.
- PHP 5.2.11 = $_POST comes empty.
- PHP 5.2.14 = Works fine.
- PHP 5.3.5 = Works fine.

Any explanation to this weird thing?

Here's a live example on a famous website: https://www.deviantart.com/users/login
try to insert "drop xxx from xxx" in username field, and type anything for password field, the form will come back without showing any errors!

Comment: How do you check if the "POST is empty". It seems like a simple SQL Injection to me. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @Hikaru-Shindo This has nothing to do with SQL. It's about html form

Comment: The words generating this behaviour are sql keywords. So it was a guess from the information you gave (PHP involved => Probably database involved). How do you check if the post is empty - You didn't answer this.

Comment: @Hikaru-Shindo I check the post by this: "echo var_dump($_POST)", which prints an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like apache *mod_security* or something similar is active. If it thinks something is SQL injection or something else that is bad, it will remove the POST data.

Comment: The word "drop" may be the trigger since it can be used to delete a database.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Intersting! Any idea which apache mod, and how to disable it?