# Disabling SecFilterScanPOST in htaccess don't do anything?

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, post, sql-injection

I posted this : [PHP 5.2.x: $_POST is empty when any field has value of "drop anywords from anywords"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294203/php-5-2-x-post-is-empty-when-any-field-has-value-of-drop-anywords-from-anywo)

I need to disable SecFilterScanPOST from htaccess
In main .htaccess, I placed:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

but still, when I post something like "drop anyword from anyword" in any **form input field**, the $_POST comes to the server empty, I guess apache thinks that this input is a SQL injection that's why it removes the posts, but it's not SQL injection!

I tried also inserting `SecFilterEngine Off` above `SecFilterScanPOST Off` but still $_POST comes empty

Please help

Comment: I don't think you can set SecFilterScanPOST in htaccess. Probably only in server config and virtual host

Comment: @Gerben many websites mention that it's possible to disable it from htaccess! I've a virtual host and I don't have access to httpd.conf, that's why I need to disable it from .htaccess

Comment: What happens if you remove the `IfModule` part? Also from the documentation: `In 2.x, the directive is now called SecRequestBodyAccess`

Comment: @Gerben without the `IfModule` a 500 internal error occurs. `SecRequestBodyAccess` is interesting, but seems like it should be applied in httpd.conf, while I need a htaccess solution (if possible)

Comment: If you get the 500 error, it means mod_security propably isn't installed at all, or that the newer function is. Have you tried SecRequestBodyAccess? If that didn't work, then there is no solution using just htaccess.

Comment: @Gerben post your last comment as an answer, I'll tick it. `SecRequestBodyAccess` doens't do anything in between the `IfModule`

Comment: I don't know what I wrote yesterday, as it doesn't make sense to me right now :-). It's not even correct English. I hope my answer below describes what fixed your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `SecRequestBodyAccess` and without the IfModule.